# cmake error Cannot find source file when file is generated by EXEC_PROGRAM

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I want to use protobuf in my project without install, so I copy the libs and headers from others, and create a FindProtobuf.cmake which include function named protobuf_generate_cpp, it generate source code files as i expect, but add_library cannot found the files, this is error:

```
Cannot find source file:

    build/basic_types.pb.h 

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

i use cmake 3.13.4 in ubuntu 18.04.1

the files is generated exactly in directory of build, and them can be show by

```
message(STATUS "header file: " ${PROTO_HDRS})
```

this is the function of protobuf_generate_cpp:

```
function(protobuf_generate_cpp PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS)
  set(SRCS_)
  set(HDRS_)
  math(EXPR idx_max "${ARGC}-1")

  foreach(idx RANGE 2 ${idx_max})
    set(FILE_PATH ${ARGV${idx}})

    if(NOT EXISTS ${FILE_PATH})
      set(FILE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}")
      if(NOT EXISTS ${FILE_PATH})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "File ${FILE_PATH} is not exists!")
      endif()
    endif()

    get_filename_component(FILE_NAME ${FILE_PATH} NAME_WE)
    get_filename_component(ABSOLUTE_FILE_NAME ${FILE_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
    get_filename_component(FILE_PATH ${FILE_PATH} PATH)

    EXEC_PROGRAM("protoc --proto_path ${FILE_PATH} --cpp_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${ABSOLUTE_FILE_NAME}")

    list(APPEND SRCS_ "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}.pb.cc ")
    list(APPEND HDRS_ "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}.pb.h ")
  endforeach()

  set(PROTO_SRCS ${SRCS_} PARENT_SCOPE)
  set(PROTO_HDRS ${HDRS_} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(protobuf_generate_cpp)
```

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS
  basic_types.proto
  calibration_parameters.proto
)
add_library(proto STATIC
  ${PROTO_HDRS}
  ${PROTO_SRCS}
)
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but generating sources as part of the configuration step seems ill-advised to me. If you update the message files, your changes will not take effect in the next build, you'd have to remember to reconfigure the project. Letting the build system do it with a custom command is much better.

Comment: I try this code in windows10 use cmake 3.14.1 just now, it works well

Comment: @StoryTeller I change the code as you said, it works well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
add_library(proto STATIC
  ${PROTO_HDRS}
  ${PROTO_SRCS}
)
```

just only can include source files.

you can try this code below,

```
add_library(proto STATIC
  ${PROTO_SRCS}
)
target_include_directory(proto 【header's dir】)
```